# List aggregate column values when column contains customer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a query on `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to select for `column_names` where it contains the name `customer`, then enter these tables and `LISTAGG` the values from these columns.

However, I get an exceptionally long error that I cannot understand:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 22:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'TB' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE
vcol VARCHAR2(128);
vtable VARCHAR(128);
BEGIN
FOR VAL IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Customer%' AND DATA_TYPE in ( 'CHAR' ,  'VARCHAR2' ))
LOOP
vcol := VAL.COLUMN_NAME;
vtable := VAL.TABLE_NAME;
FOR TB IN (
WITH A AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT vcol FROM vtable
  ) SELECT LISTAGG(vcol, ',') as cols FROM A
)
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(TB.cols);
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to table and column names using run-time variables, unless you use dynamic SQL. You could construct each statement as a string, then open the cursor dynamically using that query string:

```
DECLARE
  vstmt VARCHAR2(4000);
  vresult VARCHAR2(4000);
  vcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  FOR VAL IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Customer%')
  LOOP
    vstmt := 'WITH A AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT "' || VAL.COLUMN_NAME || '" FROM "' || VAL.TABLE_NAME || '"
  ) SELECT LISTAGG("' || VAL.COLUMN_NAME || '", '','') FROM A';

    OPEN vcursor FOR vstmt;
    LOOP
      FETCH vcursor INTO vresult;
      EXIT WHEN vcursor%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(vresult);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or as the lack of a `WITHIN GROUP` clause on your `LISTAGG` implies you're on 19c or later, you can simplify the dynamic statement to:

```
    vstmt := 'SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT "' || VAL.COLUMN_NAME || '", '','') FROM "' || VAL.TABLE_NAME || '"';
```

You can also do the same thing without PL/SQL, using an XML trick do handle the dynamic statement:

```
select table_name, column_name,
  xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select listagg(distinct "' || column_name || '", '','') as c '
      || 'from "' || table_name || '"'))
  returning content) as value_list
from all_tab_columns
where column_name like '%Customer%';
```

Your filter `where column_name like '%Customer%'` implies you have quoted identifiers. If that's not the case then the column name will be in uppercase by default; but you could search for any case with `where upper(column_name) like '%CUSTOMER%'`.

And as you're looking up the tables and columns from `all_tables`, not `user_tables`, you should really be specifying the owner as well, whether you stick with PL/SQL or use the XML approach:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name,
  xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select listagg(distinct "' || column_name || '", '','') as c '
      || 'from "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '"'))
  returning content) as value_list
from all_tab_columns
where upper(column_name) like '%CUSTOMER%';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/efik2nih) including some dummy tables.

Comment: I will have to spend some time unpacking your answer, it's very thorough and I am learning lots by going through it! Quick question -- I have implemented your first code answer but get `table or view not found` however, I can access all the tables and column names by running the `select` query inside the first for-loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Mmm, only if you're looking at another user's tables maybe; prefixing with the owner (as in my last XML version, but you can do that in the PL/SQL version too - see [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/efik2nih)) would help if so. But running exactly the code in `vstmt` should work the same. (Unless you're actually using a procedure rather than an anonymous block.)

Comment: It is an issue with the tables I have access to. They belong to different owners and so I have to access these tables by prefixing the owner. Which currently looks like `VAL.OWNER.VAL.TABLE_NAME` but I do not think `SQL` reads the second dot properly because it throws `Invalid reference to variable 'OWNER'`

Comment: But I noticed your last query with `xml` achieves this however this produces a list of `nulls`, why might this be happening?

Comment: You would need to concatenate the owner and table name with a literal dot between them - as shown in my fiddle (where I included double quotes in case you do have quotes identifiers). The XML version works in the fiddle too, so have you modified it or run it exactly as shown?